# age problem precalculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Takashi's family is a family of five of his parents, older brother, Takashi and younger brother. Currently, Takashi is half the age of his older brother and his younger brother is half his age. The total age of the whole family is 117 years old. After three years, the total age of the parents will be twice the total age of the brothers, including Takashi.

At this time, how many years from now will it be that 1.5 times the age of my brother equals the sum of the age of Takashi and my younger brother?
_____ years later

let takashi's old brother = k
so takashi =k/2
and takashi younger brother= k/4
 so (k+3) + (k+3/2)+ (k+3/4) + 2* (k+3) + (k+3/2)+ (k+3/4)= 117+3
is this right?

Comment: Care to explain what has your question to do with **any** of your tags?

Comment: You need to be more careful about distinguishing between Takashi's older and younger brothers.  In the second paragraph, are you referring to Takashi's brothers since there is no information about your brother in the question?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig im edit the questions sorry about that

Comment: @kili You've not told us anything about *your* brothers. Can you edit the second paragraph?

Comment: In the second paragraph, it looks like you meant to say $1.5$ times the age of *Takashi*'s older brother equal the sum of Takashi's age and that of *his* younger brother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In three years the total age of the family increases by $15$, so is $132$.

Your expressions for the ages in three years are wrong.  Takashi will be $\frac k2+3$, not the $k+\frac 32$ you have written.

You also need parentheses around the ages of the brothers so the $2*$ applies to them all.

Comment: thankyou but how you know its increase by 15? i mean after 3 years (k+3)/2

Comment: There are $5$ people, each of whom gets $3$ years older, so the sum of ages increases by $5\cot 3=15$.  $(k+3)/2$ is not correct for Takashi's age in $3$ years.  He is now $\frac k2$ and you have to add $3$ to that.  You have only added $\frac 32$

Comment: but for the ages after 3 years, which one is right (k+3)/2 or k/2 + 3?

Comment: Read the last sentence of my comment, please.

Comment: thankyou so much!!! i got takashi older brother is 20 years, so for last question (3/2).20= (10+x)+(5+x) solve for x ,  x=7.5 years later . please correct me if i made mistake

Comment: You should write up the answer.  The FAQ encourages you to answer your own question.  Please pay attention to the formatting to make it easy to read.  After some time (2 days?) you can accept it.